# How can i center vertical align my numbers in centered td?

Tags: html, css

I have this table

```css
table td {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">$ 11.122,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">$ 11.1,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">$ 11.122,00232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">$ 11.122,00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to have my numbers centered in the td itself, but I can't find a way to position the numbers one under another so the end result will look like this

[image]

So I need centered text in the td but the number is vertically aligned by the, and the . from the right

So at the end result will be in the centered td:

```
   $ 11.122,00
     $ 11.1,00
$ 11.122,00232
```

I don't need `text-align:right` on this, because onthat way they will be aligned just right, the numbers will be one under another, but the whole content in the td will be not centered - it will be just right aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting this, since I don't have the right reputation to comment...

```
Thank you. I thought the same thing you suggest. The problem is that the width is fixed - so what if some number is bigger than the whole width - 50% of the parent ?
```

Set your parent width to `width:auto;` and it will actually get the right width based on it's child width. So it wont be a problem if it comes a row with more characters than you want.

Comment: does not work.That way the nubmers will bot be verically alligned

Comment: try ` .container{ width:auto; display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content:center; }`

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you want the cell header centered, and the cells right aligned? If so, just add a style for the th like so:

```css
table td {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

table td span {
width: 50%;
border:1px solid red;
display:inline-block;
text-align:right;
}
.red {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">
        <span>
        $ 11.122,00
        </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red"><span>$ 11.1,00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red"><span>$ 11.122,00232</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red"><span>$ 11.122,00</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Squigins i know this.They are just right aligned but they are not centred, i need the behaviour like they are not - right aligned but they to be in the middle

Comment: So from your example Price is in the middle but the numbers down are not

Comment: @peckoski - I think this is what you want, you need additional HTML

Comment: Thank you. I tought the same thing you suggest. The probem is that the width is fixed - so what if some number is ibgger than the whole width - 50% of the parent ? Then the ayout will be broken. Is there any other way which makes this thing automatically ?